# I do not know where the formula comes from?

Tags: numerical-methods

The following formula used in numerical integration but I do not understand where it comes from. Can somebody give me any hint?
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin x dx=(1-\frac{8}{\pi^2})[f(\pi)-f(-\pi)]+\frac{16}{\pi^2}[f(\frac{\pi}{2})-f(\frac{-\pi}{2})]$$

Comment: Could it be an approximation of a series expansion of $f(x)$?

Comment: It gives an exact value when $f(x)=x^3$

Comment: It also gives an exact value for any even function.

Comment: @Paul, When the $f(x)=x^5$ the value of integration not exact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is basically [Gaussian quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature): we introduce the ansatz
$$
\int_{[-\pi,\pi]}f(x)\sin(x)\approx \sum_{i=1}^n w_if(x_i)
$$
for some conveniently chosen nodes $\{x_i\}$. The weights $\{w_i\}$ are determined by insisting that this approximation is exact for some conveniently chosen functions (e.g., the first $n$ monomials $\{x^i\}_{i\in[0,n-1]}$). Taking $\{x_i\}=\{-\pi,-\pi/2,\pi/2,\pi\}$, and requiring this ansatz to be exact for $f=1,x,x^2,x^3$ leads to the expression in the OP.

--

Equivalently, construct the [polynomial that interpolates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) $\{(x_i,f(x_i))\}$ at the nodes $\{x_i\}=\{-\pi,-\pi/2,\pi/2,\pi\}$:
$$
P_f(x)=\frac{4 \left(-2 f\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)+2 f\left(-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)-f(-\pi )+f(\pi )\right) x^3+4 \pi  \left(-f\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)-f\left(-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)+f(-\pi )+f(\pi )\right) x^2+\pi ^2 \left(8 f\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)-8 f\left(-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)+f(-\pi )-f(\pi )\right) x-\pi ^3 \left(-4 f\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)-4 f\left(-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)+f(-\pi )+f(\pi )\right)}{6 \pi ^3}
$$
and integrate explicitly.

Comment: Can you explain more with details ?

Comment: Sure. What part in particular is unclear?

Comment: I want to know how you get $(1-\frac{8}{\pi^2})$

Comment: By insisting that the ansatz is correct for $f=1,x,x^2,x^3$. You get a system of four linear equations in four unknowns $w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4$. The solution is $w_1=-1+\frac{8}{\pi^2}$, $w_2=-\frac{16}{\pi^2}$, $w_3=\frac{16}{\pi^2}$, and $w_4=1-\frac{8}{\pi^2}$.

Comment: Thank you so so much